# Insert in tables with hasOne assossiation on cakePHP

Tags: php, database, model, entity, cakephp-3.x

I am learning having a problem insert records in Tables with association "hasOne", When I insert into the **Table Users** it should also insert in **Table Customers** but is only working with Users. I've looked people had similar problems but i really don't know what I am doing wrong. I appreciate any help

My User Model

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasOne('Customers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
```

My Customer Model

```
class CustomersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('customers');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
```

My request->getData()

```
[
'Users' => [
    'Customers' => [
        'first_name' => 'name',
        'last_name' => 'test',
        'gender' => 'Male',
        'postcode' => '1234'
    ],
    'username' => 'user1',
    'password' => '12134'
],
'done' => '1'
]
```

My Action

```
public function addCustomer()
{
    //Configure::write('debug',true);
    // debug($this->request->getData());

    $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $user = $usersTable->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $usersTable->patchEntity($user,$this->request->getData(),['associated' => ['Customers']]);

        if ($usersTable->save($user)) {

            $this->Flash->success('The Customer has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'addCustomer']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Unable to add the Customer.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I though that your `User` model can not have `user_id` as its `foreinKey`